# Crash when free 2D pointer matrix in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, matrix, visual-studio-2015

I am using 2D pointer matrix in C++ (using visual studio 2015). I created the matrix and deleted it after done.

```
typedef unsigned char  U8;
typedef unsigned int   U32;
U8** A0 = new U8*[M0];
for (U32 i = 0; i < M0; ++i)
{
    A0[i] = new U8[m_L0];
}
for (U32 i = 0; i < M0; ++i){
    if (i < m_L0)
    {
        delete[] A0[i];
        A0[i] = NULL;
    }
}
delete[] A0;
A0 = NULL;
```

However, I got a error as the bellow figure. Do I need to check matrix not NULL before delete? 
[image]

Sometime, it crashed as the figure
[image]

What is my happen? Could you help me to fix it? This is my full source code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>       /* time */
#define random(x) (rand()%x)
typedef unsigned char  U8;
typedef unsigned int   U32;
class CData
{
private:
    U8* m_Data;
    U32  m_Len;
public:
    CData(void) : m_Data(NULL), m_Len(0)
    {
    }
    ~CData(void)
    {
        FreeData();
    }
    void FreeData()
    {
        if (m_Data)
        {
            delete[] m_Data;
            m_Data = NULL;
        }
    }
};
void create_and_delete_matrix()
{
    U32 M0;
    U32 m_L0;
    U32 range = 20;
    M0   = random(range);
    m_L0 = random(range);
    U8** A0 = new U8*[M0];
    for (U32 i = 0; i < M0; ++i)
    {
        A0[i] = new U8[m_L0];
    }
    for (U32 i = 0; i < M0; ++i) {
        for (U32 j = 0; j < m_L0; ++j)  {
            A0[i][j] = random(2);
            printf("%d ", A0[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    CData** D0 = new CData*[M0];
    for (U32 i = 0; i < M0; ++i){
        D0[i] = new CData();
    }

    //free A0, C0, D0 matrix
    for (U32 i = 0; i < M0; ++i){
        if (i < m_L0)
        {
            delete[] A0[i];
            A0[i] = NULL;
        }
        delete D0[i];
        D0[i] = NULL;
    }
    delete[] A0;
    A0 = NULL;

    delete[] D0;
    D0 = NULL;

}
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    unsigned int time_ui = static_cast<unsigned int>(time(NULL));
    srand(time_ui);
    for (U32 iter = 0; iter < 100; iter++){
        create_and_delete_matrix();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks mostly OK to me. The only place there could be a problem is in the lines:

```
M0   = random(range);
m_L0 = random(range);
```

With that, it is possible for `M0` and/or `m_L0` to be zero. I would suggest changing them to:

```
M0   = random(range) + 1;
m_L0 = random(range) + 1;
```

or add special logic to account for the cases where one of them is set to zero.

Comment: Why should 0 be a problem? Do you see any case in the code in which it doesn't do the right thing?

Comment: @6502, I couldn't find anything in the standard that indicates whether passing `0` to `operator new []` is OK or not.

Comment: @6502, thanks for the link. Based on that, calling `operator new []` with `0` as argument should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

The code seems ok.

May be you defined (or you are using) a custom global memory allocator for objects or for arrays that doesn't handle correctly requests of 0 bytes?